# Dropdown values not added in ajax call back

Tags: jquery, html, css

Dropdown values not added in ajax call back  This my html code

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="SeatInfo" class="floatleft"></div>
    <div id="ClusterInfo" class="floatright">
        <label id="Floor">Floor</label>
        <select id="FloorInfo">
            @foreach (SelectListItem item in ViewBag.data)
            {
                <option value=@item.Value>@item.Text</option>
            }
        </select>
        <label id="Seat">Seat</label>
        <select id="SeatInfo">

        </select>

    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#FloorInfo").change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/SeatInfo",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify({ FloorID: parseInt(value) }),
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#SeatInfo').empty(); // clear the current elements in select box
                    var dataDetails = data.split(':');
                    for (var i=0;i<dataDetails.length; i++) {
                        debugger;  var info = dataDetails[i].split(',');
                        $('#SeatInfo').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', info[0]).text(info[1]));
                    }

            }});
        });
    });

</script>
```

callback result data value : "Testing ,2017:sf ,2018:dfsad ,2019:"

Second dropdown values not added after done selection changed  ? I able to get proper data in debugging

Comment: Is this Aspx Or Jsp ?

Comment: What is the result of debugging it? Are the values what you think they should be? When I pull the `$('#SeatInfo').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', info[0]).text(info[1]));` line out and use hard coded strings, it works fine. http://jsbin.com/naxabupa/1/edit?html,output

Comment: What have you done to narrow down the problem? Is the function being called at all (add `console.log` or something to check)? Is the HTTP request being made (Look in the Net tab of your developer tools)? Is the response what you expect? If you `console.log(data)` inside the success function, do you get the value you expect? Does the split work? Does the code enter the loop at all?

Comment: i got this result in data

Comment: yeah adding successfully but not showing in dropdown

Comment: you have two elements with same id `SeatInfo` try this http://jsfiddle.net/66sqf/45/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Can you do a log of the data? also try to use `data = $.parseJSON(data)` to make sure the data is parsed back from json. Also, i would do it like this

```
var option = "";
option += "<option value=" + data to fill with + "></option>";
$("#SeatInfo").html(option);
```

It is better than appending...

Comment: That data being sent from the server isn't JSON, using `parseJSON` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have both a Div and a Select with the id `SeatInfo`. Since an id is intended for a single element, only the first element in your page (in your case the div) gets the id, and thus the options are not added to your select. Rename your div to something else.

Comment: Good spot. Adding the div breaks the [test case](http://jsbin.com/naxabupa/2/edit?html,output) I created earlier. +1

Comment: @user3819410 please upvote and accept my answer if it solved your problem. it rewards both of us with rep and provides a possible solution for users with the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using (Json)

```
 $("#FloorInfo").change(function () {
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.getJSON("/Home/SeatInfo", { id: id }, function (myData) {
                var select = $("#SeatInfo");
                select.empty();
                select.append($('<option/>', {
                    value: "0",
                    text: "--Select One--", selected: true
                }))
                $.each(myData, function (index, itemData) {
                    select.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: itemData.Value,
                        text: itemData.Text
                    }));
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: This is a massive game of spot-the-difference where most of it just uses alternative syntax to achieve the same effect (for no apparent reason) but also changes the HTTP request so instead of sending JSON in a POST request it sends form encoded data in a GET request and also tries the parse the response as JSON (which it isn't). You don't appear to have fixed any problems, but you've introduced three new ones.

Comment: It completely fails to identify the problem (which Nate spotted).